# How can flutter navigator continuously return data?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

E.g:

```
1.in ListPage:   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed (DetailPage)
2.in DetailPage: Navigator.of(context).pushNamed (EditPage)
3.in EditPage:   Navigator.of(context).pop(needRefresh)
```

E.g:

There are three pages:

ListPage-> DetailPage-> EditPage

If the EditPage is modified, I need to refresh the DetailPage and refresh the ListPage when I click the back button on the DetailPage page; otherwise, I do nothing! Not EditPage returns ListPage directly

Comment: Your question is quite unclear but I think that [`popUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html) method could help.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand? Can you provide a clear example?

Comment: You would benefit from checking the question guidelines at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to refresh the page on pop. You can use .then function in push function in detail page.

Ex.,

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, SubscriptionPage.id,).then((value) {
_getData();
});
```